# select all checkbox be default if the route.path includes /add

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

In my Vue code, I have a list of check-boxes, so whenever I add a new usergroup, by default all check-boxes should be selected except the disabled one. I have to condition and function code, but not sure where to include the function. Whenever I add a new usergroup, by default all checkbox should be selected.

I have the method, but need to know where and how to call it.

```
<li><a @click.prevent="selectAll" id="cardSelectAllAId"> 
    SelectAll</a></li>

  <single-checkbox class="checkbox "
             inputId="card.data.id"
                 v-if="card.data.id"
         @change="change(card.data)"
         :value="card.data.selected"
    :disabled="!card.data.licenseEnabled">


  selectAll() {
   for (let i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i += 1) {
    if (this.cards[i].selected !== undefined) {
     this.cards[i].selected = true;
    }
  },


  default() {
  const currentRoute = this.$route.path;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.features.length; i += 1) {
    if (currentRoute.includes('/admin/users/usergroup/add/')) {
      this.features[i].selected = true;
    } else {
      this.features[i].selected = false;
    }
  }
},
```

I also need a method to not include disabled check box in select all function.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it the solution is to add v-bind in the checkbox and call the method in computed

```
     v-bind:class="{ 'checkbox' : isdefault }".
```

but still i have one bug,
while selecting all , the disabled checkbox is also gets selected , i need to fix that not to include disabled checkbox in the selection.